# UIButton is partially red when enabling Show Blended Layers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, transparency, opacity

I would like to improve performance by making my views opaque where appropriate. I have a `UIButton`  that is showing red in the simulator - it's only red around the text of the button, not the entire frame. In the Storyboard, I've enabled Opaque and changed the background color from clear to white, yet it still shows red in the simulator.

How do I change that to green so that it's fully opaque and not trying to work with transparency?

Note that `UILabel`s are fully green when you change its background and opaque to YES.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am use following code in your case:

```
[button.titleLabel setOpaque:YES];
[button.titleLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]]; 
// or which-you-want-color
```

Obviously, you should keep weak reference to your button.

Pretty works. Button size smaller than the screenshot size.

[image]

Comment: Worked for me even without `setBackgroundColor` (iOS11). Just plain `[button.titleLabel setOpaque:YES];`. But of course, if you eventually will set `backgroundColor` as `clearColor` blending will be performed regardless of `isOpaque` property.

Comment: Be careful with using this though because if your UIButton is in a tableview and you have cell selection color enabled, then the button background color will still stay white even when the cell selection color around is shows something else.

Comment: The `setOpaque` is not necessary. Only the background

Answer (score 0):

I believe the UIButton is made of a couple of views such as titleLabel. It may be possible to enumerate the UIButtons' subview and set them each to opaque.

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
for(UIView *subview in [button subviews]){
    subview.opaque = YES;
}
```

Comment: Hmm that didn't do the trick. I changed it to TypeSystem because the button type is just the default - it's the cell with the custom style.

Comment: That was just for example. You can leave your button how it already is and iterate it's subviews.

It was just a thought.

Comment: I see what you mean. I changed it to my specific button but the result is still the same. I even changed the background in addition to opaque.

Comment: Maybe you setting background image for different stets and this UIImage is not opaque.